# Printing to main stdout in IPython Notebook from other parallel engines

Tags: parallel-processing, stdout, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working in an IPython Notebook.
I am running a function across different engines and would like to see what it prints.

**Example:**

```
def simple(a):
    print a+40;
    return a+20

A = range(20);
dview.map_sync(simple, A);
```

I would like this functionality because I'm running a function that runs for a long time and I am using `print` statements to keep track of its progress.